# Yup compact on array in nested object not applying

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have the following object, and can't seem to find a way to have Yup ignore falsey values in an array.

```
const schema = object().shape({
   myAttribute: object({
      myFirstValue: array(string())
        .ensure()
        .compact(), //this isn't working
      mySecondValue: array(string())
         .ensure()
        .compact() //this isn't working
   })
)}
```

The validation of the array and string work, however, the compact isn't. Is there an understanding of how `compact` works that don't apply in this situation? I am using this for a Formik form.

Comment: can you share a codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

Are you restructuring the type methods from the main yup object? I'd try:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
   myAttribute: Yup.object().shape({
      myFirstValue: Yup.array().of(Yup.string()).compact(),
      mySecondValue: Yup.array().of(Yup.string()).compact()
   })
)}
```

Comment: I am importing as `import { object, string, number, boolean, date, array } from "yup"`. I tried your approach with no luck.